# Plotting power spectral density from transfer function

Tags: plotting, signal-processing

I am new to signal processing. The equations below are given in $LaTeX$.

I have the following transfer function (from the Dryden Model) for the two-sided Power Spectral Density:

$$S(w) = \frac{\sigma_u ^2 \tau_u}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+(\tau_u w)^2}$$

I would like to plot the above as: Power Spectral Density, dB vs. w

Any help on this would be appreciated. (please use any numerical values for $\sigma_u, \tau_u$)

I also need to calculate the auto-correlation function by taking the inverse Fourier transform (call it `R(s)` ) of `S(w)`.

Finally, I want to compute

$$S1(w) = \int_{0}^{\infty} R(s) \cos (ws) ds$$

I would really appreciate someone's kindest help and advice in this regard. Thank you!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
L := 50
Umc := 4.31
Su[ω_, σ_, τ_] := (σ^2 *τ/π )*1/(1 \
+ (τ *ω)^2)
Sw[ω_, σ_, τ_] := (σ^2 *τ/(2*π \
))*(1 + 3*(τ* ω)^2)/(1 + (τ*ω)^2)^2

Ru[s_] := InverseFourierTransform[Su[ω, 1, L/Umc], ω, s]

S2 [ω_] := Integrate[Ru[s]*Cos[2*ω*s], {s, 0, Infinity}]

Plot[S2[ω] , {ω, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: You can get your latex to show as Mathematica code like this: `ToExpression["S(w) = \\ frac{\\ sigma_u ^2 \\ tau_u}{\\ pi} \\ frac{1}{1+(\\ tau_u w)^2}",TeXForm]` and this gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fMbm6.png)

Comment: @Kuba Yes it is

Comment: @Nasser thanks so much...I'll keep this in mind for next time

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple sites (this is to avoid duplicated efforts). If you're doing this in Mathematica, please include the relevant code.

Comment: @rm-rf sorry about that....i have deleted my other post..i have no idea as to which functions in mathematica can do this for me so unfortunately i have no code at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want a dB PK ω plot you can use the built-in [`BodePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BodePlot.html) function.

```
s[ω_, σ_, τ_] := σ^2 τ/π 1/(1 + (τ ω)^2)

BodePlot[Tooltip[s[ω, 1, 2]], ImageSize -> 550, Frame -> True, 
            PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[20, 1]], 
            Directive[Thick, ColorData[20, 9]]}, Frame -> False, 
            AspectRatio -> 1/2.25, GridLines -> Automatic, 
            GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   [image: Mathematica graphics]

I will leave the rest to you - [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html) and [`InverseFourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseFourierTransform.html) should do the trick :)

Comment: thanks for the help...I am having a problem in plotting now..my function `S2[w]` outputs values for `{w,0,1}` but nothing shows up on the plot...i have no idea what I am doing wrong...i'll put the comment above...can you please take a look? sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Stoc Have you resolved the plotting issue ?